# Использование boost::MPL в вычислении таблицы умножения

Tags: c++, boost

Задача простая: для заданного n вычислить элементы табл. умножения: i j (i = 1 ... n, j = 1 ... n). Полученную таблицу вывести на печать.
Но осложняется тем, что нужно все вычисления, а также вывод таблицы сделать с помощью библиотеки boost::MPL, в которой я плохо разбираюсь ).
Написал такой код:

```
const int n = 5;
typedef range_c<int, 1, n> numbers;
typedef vector<int_<3>> data;       // int_<3> для примера
template <class T> struct wrap{};
typedef mpl::fold<
    numbers,
    data,
    mpl::push_back<_1, mpl::plus<int_<3>, back<_1>>>
>::type fold_line;

struct print_value {
    template <class col>
    void operator()(wrap <col>) const {
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << col::value;
    }
};

template <class row> void print_line() {
    mpl::for_each< row, wrap <_> >(print_value());
    std::cout << std::endl;
};

struct line {
    void operator()() const {
        print_line<fold_line>();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Table " << n << "x" << n << std::endl;
    mpl::for_each<numbers>(line());
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Но вылетает ошибка:
**error C2064: результатом вычисления фрагмента не является функция, принимающая 1 аргументов boost\mpl\for_each.hpp**

Кроме того, если я правильно понял, как это работает, тут должна вывестись 5 раз строка "3 6 9 12 15", то есть только одна строка таблицы. А как сделать так, чтобы можно было передавать mpl::fold разные data, то есть не `vector<int_<3>>`, а `vector<int_<n>>`, где n - текущий номер строки таблицы, и в строке кода

```
mpl::push_back<_1, mpl::plus<int_<3>, back<_1>>>
```

Вместо `int_<3>` тоже использовать что-то вроде `int_<n>`?

Comment: Приложите полные исходники, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

У вас функции печати строк, элементов и т.д. не принимают никаких параметров. Как они узнаю, что им печатать?

Полиморфизм по типу параметра функции реализуется через шаблон

```
struct line {
  template< typename T >
  void operator()(T &v) const {
      print_line(v);
  }
};
```

В такую функцию можно передавать любой параметр `int_<n>`